# Slighly cutting your body when your skin gets red (not bleeding yet) or when you bleed very slightly

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

How do you mention these types of wounds?
Based on my mother language and dictionaries' definitions, the only word which can work here is: **"scratch"**. So I need to know if the following sentences are natural to you:

> - Come on; get up! **That's just a small scratch.**

Or in a predicative sentence:

> - When I was playing football, fell down and **got some scratches on my leg**.

Do those bold parts sound idiomatic in English?!
Please consider the following images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's called "scrapped"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like **scraped** skin.

**Scratched** skin usually has a pattern of lines, whether done by finger nails, or by some sharp / pointy object (e.g. thorns in a bush, a stray wire...).

Scratch by thorn:

[image: scratched skin by thorn]

Scratches by fingernails

[image: scratched skin by fingernails]

---

Note: In the title you wrote "Slightly cutting your body when your skin gets red". Please be aware that "**cutting**" is not the proper word for any of the pictures on this page, even if it looks somehow similar with a thorn scratch - the main difference being that a cut is a lot deeper and potentially (a lot) more dangerous.